# bash to move select fields to match file prefix in two directories

Tags: bash

In the below `bash` I am trying to use the prefix `123_Last-First` of `file1` to match to prefix `123_Last-First` in `file2`. There will always be a match found (that is if there is a `file1` there has to be a `file2`). In `file2` the contents of `$5`,`&6`,and `$7` (always tab-delimited)

`$5 = Total_Targets with value under it that can be a decimal or integer`

`$6 = Targets_less_than250x with value under it that can be a decimal or integer`

`$7 = Percent_more_than250x with value under it that can be a decimal or integer`

are copied to it under the header `Quality metrics`. The below executes but there is  no output produced. I have added comments to help and show my thinking. Thank you :).

**file1  in /home/cmccabe/oncomine/250x**

```
123_Last-First_250x.txt
Position    Gene    Type    Reads   Total_Targets   Targets_less_than250x   Percent_more_than250x
chr4:55141051   PDGFRA  NOCALL  13  2353    1   99.9575
```

**file2  in /home/cmccabe/oncomine/report**

```
123_Last-First_oca.txt
Controls:
4 expression controls detected
```

**output  in /home/cmccabe/oncomine/report/final**

```
123_Last-First_oncomine.txt
Quality metrics:
Total_Targets   Targets_less_than250x   Percent_more_than250x
2353    1   99.9575
Controls:
4 expression controls detected
```

**awk**

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$5,$6,$7]=$0;next}$1 in A' OFS=\'t'  123_Last-First_250x.txt 123_Last-First_oca.txt | awk 'NR>1{print "Quality metrics:"}' > /home/cmccabe/oncomine/report/final/123_Last-First_oncomine.txt
```

Comment: `for file1 in "/home/cmccabe/Desktop/oca/250x/*.txt"` only iterates once, with the exact string `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/oca/250x/*.txt`. Globs are only expanded outside quotes.

Comment: Please resolve issues found by http://shellcheck.net/ **before** asking questions here, and isolate a single, specific issue per question. As it is, this doesn't focus on any specific error, but encompasses the whole of your larger goal.

Comment: I ran the script through shellcheck.net and get a parser error on line 11... ^-- SC1083: This { is literal. Check expression (missing ;/\n?) or quote it.... I understand the error but am not sure how to address it as the `${p}` is a variable with the filename prefix.  Thank you  very much :).

Comment: I suspect that when you wrote `OFS=\'t'`, you meant `OFS='\t'` or `OFS=$'\t'`; as it is, the backslash makes the first single-quote literal, which throws off the rest of the script.

Comment: i didn't even see that and will try again and post back.  I tried and the script executes with no output. Thank you :).

Comment: Run `bash -x yourscript` to trace execution. Ideally, this will let you identify the specific point of failure, so you can ask a smaller and more-focused question (ideally one with a [mcve]). BTW, `[[ -f file2 ]]` is looking for a file named `file2`; I'm guessing you instead want `[[ -f $file2 ]]`.

Comment: I ran `bash -x` and found a couple issues with the filenames and fixed them, I then hardcoded the ~$file1` and `$file2` and the `awk` does execute, but the resulting output is empty... so the issue is the `awk` is not doing what I think. I updated the post to reflect this as well.Thank you very much for your help :).

Comment: Thank you very much all your help, the script executes as expected :).